# Check that array is empty, but not null

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of objects (`Object[] array`), and I want to check whether it is empty, but fail fast if it is null with NPE or any other exception.

I know that I can do the following check

```
array.length == 0
```

but e.g. in case of `String` or collections it is not recommended practice, IntelliJ even has inspection for that:

> Reports any `.size()` or `.length()` comparisons with a 0 literal which can be replaced with a call to `.isEmpty()`.

Is there any replacement for `.isEmpty()` for arrays?

There is [ArrayUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.Object[])](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.Object[])), but it also checks for `null`, while I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: It would be simple to write the desired method yourself.

Comment: what about getLength() from java.lang.Object

Comment: Strings and collections are objects, so isEmpty() makes sense. An array of whatever, even objects, is just that, an array. It contains no "smarts", sof if you need smarts, you need to add it yourself - it does make them super lightweight though.

Comment: @Jesper it must be the fun to ask questions on SO

Comment: use `array.length == 0` and ignore intellijs useless tip, because isEmpty() obviously doesn't do what you want. be sure to check for null first

Comment: I don't think Intellij provides an inspection for arrays because there is no such method

Comment: @PhilippSander IntelliJ doesn't warn for arrays, it warns for strings and collections as stated in question

Comment: Plus, being non null is a pre-requisite to being empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `.size()` is method, its implementation is hidden. And you can't be sure that this method optimized (there's a *possibility*, that some collections, for example, enumerate items every time you call `.size()` method). That is why computing the `.size()` of collection *could* be expensive. In the same time, `.isEmpty()` can checks just is there at least one item in collection, and return result.

But `.length` is just a field. It does nothing, just returns a value. There are no calculations. This field just stores the length of array with fixed size.

I believe that `.size()` and `.length` are totally different things and in this case they can not be compared, as well as collections and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to be to write such a method yourself. It would be fairly trivial. Something like the following

```
public boolean isArrayEmpty(Object[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        //Throw nullpointer exception
        //An easy of method of doing this would be accessing any array field (for example: array.length)
    }
    return (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(array));
}
```

That being said, there's very little reason why `array.length == 0` would be harmful. It's the simplest, cleanest way to do this and does exactly what you want. Most likely part of the reason for `ArrayUtils.isEmpty` is to allow easy testing of whether or not a array is empty *or* null, a relatively common need, but you don't want to do that.

Comment: Why throw your own NullPointerException? Just do `return array.length == 0`. And ArrayUtils is not native Java

Comment: @cricket_007 That would be one  way of doing it. I don't know what the op wants to do. But I'll add that to the answer as a suggestion as a possible method of doing it. Thanks for your input!

Comment: returning `ArrayUtils.isEmpty(array)` is a very roundabout way of returning `array.length == 0`. I would rather fix IntelliJ's idea of what is good or bad rather than using `ArrayUtils` for this task